# How to start a VPN service on device reboot without device administrator permissions?

Tags: android, vpn

I want my VPN service to automatically start when a device reboots. Previously, I achieved this functionality by using the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast. However, I've noticed that some phone manufacturers have started blocking this broadcast, making it unreliable.

I recently came across the "Always-on VPN" feature in the Android documentation, which seems to solve this problem. However, I would like to implement it without requiring device administrator permissions, as I want to avoid requesting elevated privileges from the user.

Could someone provide guidance on how to implement the "Always-on VPN" feature without using device administrator permissions? I would like my VPN service to start automatically after a device reboot, ensuring a seamless experience for users.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you share the Broadcast receiver code in which you're starting your service on boot?

Comment: <receiver
            android:name=".view.receivers.CustomBootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

but there is no problem with the code, It is working perfect untill these manufacturers restrictions

Comment: No I mean, the class - `CustomBootReceiver` code